# Prevent triggering Angular Material md-swipe-left/md-swipe-right directive's function on parent element

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a parent element that fills 100% of page height and several child elements inside it. Swipe-right on the parent toggles side menu, but I want to prevent this function and trigger `childAction()` when I swipe-right on it's child.

```
<div id="parent" md-swipe-right="toggleSideMenu()">
    <div id="child" md-swipe-right="childAction()">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `md-swipe-right` like all other event directives provides `$event` as a local.<sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/swipe/swipe.js#L89)</sup>

In your HTML include `$event` as an argument to your function.

```
<div id="parent" md-swipe-right="toggleSideMenu()">
    <div id="child" md-swipe-right="childAction($event)">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller invoke the `stopPropagation()` function.

```
$scope.childAction = function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

For more information on `$event` see, [AngularJS Developer Guide -- expressions -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)